# CKEditor content (text) disappears on Responsive Site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, responsive-design, ckeditor

CKEditor loads in fine, and editable content area works 5/10 times.

The other times, the whole area is not selectable by mouse or tab key. Likewise, if it is loading field text from the dbase, all the text is missing.

Weird thing is that resizing the window corrects the error instantly. But there's little consistency in a window size that causes it to break. Sometimes a maxed window on Macbook works, sometimes it doesn't.

For simplicity, I recorded a 3 min screencast that illustrates the behaviour:

[image: My screencast]

My call to CKEditor is simple:

```
<script>
   CKEDITOR.replace( 'friendlyDesc<?php echo $row['jobId']; ?>' );
</script>
```

I load it in the < head > like this:

```
<script src="../js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

And here's the page when it loads in:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="friendlyDesc">Job Description</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" name="friendlyDesc28" id="friendlyDesc28" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;">&lt;p&gt;We are growing so quickly it's insane.&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
  <div id="cke_friendlyDesc28" class="cke_2 cke cke_reset cke_chrome cke_editor_friendlyDesc28 cke_ltr cke_browser_webkit" dir="ltr" lang="en" role="application" aria-labelledby="cke_friendlyDesc28_arialbl"><span id="cke_friendlyDesc28_arialbl" class="cke_voice_label">Rich Text Editor, friendlyDesc28</span>
    <div class="cke_inner cke_reset" role="presentation"><span id="cke_2_top" class="cke_top cke_reset_all" role="presentation" style="height: auto; -webkit-user-select: none;"><span id="cke_46" class="cke_voice_label">Editor toolbars</span><span id="cke_2_toolbox" class="cke_toolbox" role="group" aria-labelledby="cke_46"
      onmousedown="return false;"><span id="cke_47" class="cke_toolbar" aria-labelledby="cke_47_label" role="toolbar"><span id="cke_47_label" class="cke_voice_label">Editing</span><span class="cke_toolbar_start"></span><span class="cke_toolgroup"
      role="presentation"><a id="cke_48" class="cke_button cke_button__scayt cke_button_off " href="javascript:void('Spell Check As You Type')" title="Spell Check As You Type" tabindex="-1" hidefocus="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_48_label" aria-haspopup="true" onkeydown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(37,event);" onfocus="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(38,event);" onmousedown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(39,event);" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(40,this);return false;"><span class="cke_button_icon cke_button__scayt_icon" style="background-image:url(http://employeeripple.com/app/js/ckeditor/plugins/icons.png?t=DBAA);background-position:0 -528px;background-size:auto;">&nbsp;</span>
        <span
        id="cke_48_label" class="cke_button_label cke_button__scayt_label" aria-hidden="false">Spell Check As You Type</span><span class="cke_button_arrow"></span>
      </a>
    </span><span class="cke_toolbar_end"></span></span><span id="cke_49" class="cke_toolbar" aria-labelledby="cke_49_label" role="toolbar"><span id="cke_49_label" class="cke_voice_label">Basic Styles</span><span class="cke_toolbar_start"></span>
    <span
    class="cke_toolgroup" role="presentation"><a id="cke_50" class="cke_button cke_button__bold  cke_button_off" href="javascript:void('Bold')" title="Bold" tabindex="-1" hidefocus="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_50_label" aria-haspopup="false" onkeydown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(41,event);"
    onfocus="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(42,event);" onmousedown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(43,event);" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(44,this);return false;"><span class="cke_button_icon cke_button__bold_icon" style="background-image:url(http://employeeripple.com/app/js/ckeditor/plugins/icons.png?t=DBAA);background-position:0 0px;background-size:auto;">&nbsp;</span><span id="cke_50_label" class="cke_button_label cke_button__bold_label" aria-hidden="false">Bold</span></a>
    <a
    id="cke_51" class="cke_button cke_button__italic  cke_button_off" href="javascript:void('Italic')" title="Italic" tabindex="-1" hidefocus="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_51_label" aria-haspopup="false" onkeydown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(45,event);"
    onfocus="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(46,event);" onmousedown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(47,event);" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(48,this);return false;"><span class="cke_button_icon cke_button__italic_icon" style="background-image:url(http://employeeripple.com/app/js/ckeditor/plugins/icons.png?t=DBAA);background-position:0 -24px;background-size:auto;">&nbsp;</span><span id="cke_51_label"
    class="cke_button_label cke_button__italic_label" aria-hidden="false">Italic</span>
  </a>
</span><span class="cke_toolbar_end"></span></span><span id="cke_52" class="cke_toolbar" aria-labelledby="cke_52_label" role="toolbar"><span id="cke_52_label" class="cke_voice_label">Paragraph</span><span class="cke_toolbar_start"></span>
<span
class="cke_toolgroup" role="presentation">
<a id="cke_53" class="cke_button cke_button__numberedlist  cke_button_off" href="javascript:void('Insert/Remove Numbered List')" title="Insert/Remove Numbered List" tabindex="-1" hidefocus="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_53_label"
aria-haspopup="false" onkeydown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(49,event);" onfocus="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(50,event);" onmousedown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(51,event);" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(52,this);return false;"><span class="cke_button_icon cke_button__numberedlist_icon" style="background-image:url(http://employeeripple.com/app/js/ckeditor/plugins/icons.png?t=DBAA);background-position:0 -408px;background-size:auto;">&nbsp;</span>
<span
id="cke_53_label" class="cke_button_label cke_button__numberedlist_label" aria-hidden="false">Insert/Remove Numbered List</span>
</a>
<a id="cke_54" class="cke_button cke_button__bulletedlist  cke_button_off" href="javascript:void('Insert/Remove Bulleted List')" title="Insert/Remove Bulleted List" tabindex="-1" hidefocus="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_54_label"
aria-haspopup="false" onkeydown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(53,event);" onfocus="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(54,event);" onmousedown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(55,event);" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(56,this);return false;"><span class="cke_button_icon cke_button__bulletedlist_icon" style="background-image:url(http://employeeripple.com/app/js/ckeditor/plugins/icons.png?t=DBAA);background-position:0 -360px;background-size:auto;">&nbsp;</span>
<span
id="cke_54_label" class="cke_button_label cke_button__bulletedlist_label" aria-hidden="false">Insert/Remove Bulleted List</span>
</a><span class="cke_toolbar_separator" role="separator"></span><a id="cke_55" class="cke_button cke_button__outdent cke_button_disabled " href="javascript:void('Decrease Indent')" title="Decrease Indent" tabindex="-1" hidefocus="true"
role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_55_label" aria-haspopup="false" aria-disabled="true" onkeydown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(57,event);" onfocus="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(58,event);" onmousedown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(59,event);"
onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(60,this);return false;"><span class="cke_button_icon cke_button__outdent_icon" style="background-image:url(http://employeeripple.com/app/js/ckeditor/plugins/icons.png?t=DBAA);background-position:0 -216px;background-size:auto;">&nbsp;</span><span id="cke_55_label" class="cke_button_label cke_button__outdent_label" aria-hidden="false">Decrease Indent</span></a>
<a
id="cke_56" class="cke_button cke_button__indent cke_button_disabled" href="javascript:void('Increase Indent')" title="Increase Indent" tabindex="-1" hidefocus="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_56_label" aria-haspopup="false"
onkeydown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(61,event);" onfocus="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(62,event);" onmousedown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(63,event);" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(64,this);return false;"
aria-disabled="true"><span class="cke_button_icon cke_button__indent_icon" style="background-image:url(http://employeeripple.com/app/js/ckeditor/plugins/icons.png?t=DBAA);background-position:0 -168px;background-size:auto;">&nbsp;</span><span id="cke_56_label"
class="cke_button_label cke_button__indent_label" aria-hidden="false">Increase Indent</span>
</a>
</span><span class="cke_toolbar_end"></span></span><span id="cke_57" class="cke_toolbar" aria-labelledby="cke_57_label" role="toolbar"><span id="cke_57_label" class="cke_voice_label">Links</span><span class="cke_toolbar_start"></span>
<span
class="cke_toolgroup" role="presentation"><a id="cke_58" class="cke_button cke_button__link  cke_button_off" href="javascript:void('Link')" title="Link" tabindex="-1" hidefocus="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_58_label" aria-haspopup="false" onkeydown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(65,event);"
onfocus="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(66,event);" onmousedown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(67,event);" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(68,this);return false;"><span class="cke_button_icon cke_button__link_icon" style="background-image:url(http://employeeripple.com/app/js/ckeditor/plugins/icons.png?t=DBAA);background-position:0 -288px;background-size:auto;">&nbsp;</span><span id="cke_58_label" class="cke_button_label cke_button__link_label" aria-hidden="false">Link</span></a>
<a
id="cke_59" class="cke_button cke_button__unlink cke_button_disabled " href="javascript:void('Unlink')" title="Unlink" tabindex="-1" hidefocus="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_59_label" aria-haspopup="false"
aria-disabled="true" onkeydown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(69,event);" onfocus="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(70,event);" onmousedown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(71,event);" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(72,this);return false;"><span class="cke_button_icon cke_button__unlink_icon" style="background-image:url(http://employeeripple.com/app/js/ckeditor/plugins/icons.png?t=DBAA);background-position:0 -312px;background-size:auto;">&nbsp;</span>
<span
id="cke_59_label" class="cke_button_label cke_button__unlink_label" aria-hidden="false">Unlink</span>
</a>
</span><span class="cke_toolbar_end"></span></span>
</span>
</span>
<div id="cke_2_contents" class="cke_contents cke_reset" role="presentation" style="height: 200px;"><span id="cke_63" class="cke_voice_label">Press ALT 0 for help</span>
<iframe src="" frameborder="0" class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" title="Rich Text Editor, friendlyDesc28" aria-describedby="cke_63" tabindex="0"
allowtransparency="true" style="width: 536px; height: 100%;"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

I would appreciate suggestions on how to hunt down the cause, as it's a frustrating error that I can't find the cause of. I'm wondering if there's something perhaps in my CSS, or in Javascript calls that is affecting it.

I'll also note this is a little different to other questions on here about disappearing instances of CKEditor, as those involve the whole WYSIWIG interface disappearing. In my case, it's just the content in the editor than vanishes.

Comment: Same Problem ... !! no issue ?